# Increase jquery variable by 1 on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having issues increasing a variable by 1 every time I scroll. I successfully increase the variable by 1, but only once. This is the code I got. I need to increase the variable page.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).scroll(function (e) {
                 currentPage = 0;
                if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 10) {
                    ++currentPage;
                    $.getJSON("../campus/Settings/TranslationSettings.ashx?command=show&page=" + currentPage + "&Lang=en", function (data) {
                        var items = [];
                        $.each(data.Keys, function (key, val) {

                            $("<ul/>", {
                                "class": "translateinfo",
                                html: "<li class='keystring'><span class='label'>text string:</span>" + val["text string"] + "</li>" + "<li class='autotranslate'><span class='label'>Automated translation:</span>" + val["automated translation"] + "</li>" + "<li class='functionnumber'><span class='label'>Function Number:</span>" + val["function number"] + "</li>" + "<li class='translateurl'><span class='label'>URL:</span>" + val["url"] + "</li>"
                            }).appendTo("#updatepanel");
                        });


                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you copy/paste your entire code. But you're recreating currentPage everytime the user scroll

Working fiddle, I create the variable before the scroll loop.

```
var currentPage = 0;

        $(document).scroll(function (e) {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 10) {
                ++currentPage;
                console.log(currentPage);
            }
        })
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dCr3Z/